# Too many requests to BigQuery when running multiple Google Cloud Functions off the same trigger

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I'm guessing this is a really simple question but I don't know the terminology for it; hopefully it's a quick answer and close!

Info on the project: It's a Python 3.8 project which is based on Google Cloud Platform, using Cloud Functions, BigQuery, Secret Manager, PubSub, Scheduler and uses a service account (not the project default) for authentication. Aforementioned service account has appropriate permissions for everything it does - works great when triggered in isolation.

I've got a couple of Google Cloud Functions applications I'd like to execute at exactly the same time. I'm using a single Service Account for authentication between both apps and in the same GCP project; keeps things nice and simple as I already have to set up quite a few things if I want to make another instance. Unfortunately when I execute one of my apps while the other one is running, the initial one will fail, presumably because the service account on the new one now has the authentication.

Is there any way to fix this so both apps are able to continue to be authenticated using the same credentials? Would it be as easy as using different secret versions within Google Secret Manager?

Normally I'd just delay it but I'm mostly looking for a way to make my app scalable and not conflict with other apps which are running.

**Update:**
Looking at the logs it seems like there might be an issue with how my BigQuery functions specifically are being called. It seems to be quota related, specifically to do with table updates and polling.py, but I'm not sure what might be causing it? Seems unusual.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 149, in view_func
        function(data, context)
      File "/workspace/main.py", line 1016, in main
        primaryRequest(ga_sessions_1g1, reportName='ga_sessions_1g1')
      File "/workspace/main.py", line 1003, in primaryRequest
        write_to_bq(reportName)
      File "/workspace/main.py", line 958, in write_to_bq
        job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 631, in result
        return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 134, in result
        raise self._exception
    google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
```

Here's the function which contains line 958 as above:

```
    def write_to_bq(bqLookup):
        client = bigquery.Client(credentials=scopedBqCredentials, project=bqCredentials.project_id,)
        bqTableLookup = bqTableDict.get(bqLookup)
        table_id = f'{gcpProject}.{bqDataset}.{bqTableLookup}'
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=0, autodetect=False,
        )
        with open('/tmp/result.csv', "rb") as source_file:
            job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)
        job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
        table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
        print("Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
            table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id))
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Using the same service account in several function won't cause disruptions of running functions. the issue is elsewhere. Can you share some pieces of code on where the issue occur?

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere you seem to be correct. I've updated the original post with additional info including a traceback and some code.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a load job with the method `client.load_table_from_file()`. With BigQuery you are limited to [1500 load job per table and per day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) (1 per minutes in constant flow)

*Note: The 403 error led you to permission error. A better error code could be use by BigQuery API (529 for example) in case of quota excedeed.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure how this would have happened as both functions are pointed to updating different BigQuery tables. The local version of my script which is functionally the same as above can also run for hours on end without an issue. What's even more mysterious is that I ran my Cloud Functions scripts last night using a scheduled PubSub and there was no error; everything completed successfully. Do you still think the quota might have been an issue?

Comment: The quota is clearly the reason of the fail (it's clear in the error message). I don't know the context of your project, if you stress BigQuery with a lot of load job or not.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the reply. It surprises me that this is a quota problem because it's not a very intensive script. The project just makes a Google Analytics call, stores it in CSV, then appends the result to a BigQuery table. It loops day-by-day, but both projects are in different BigQuery datasets so there shouldn't be a problem with quotas.